# Android studio, login form cant connect on mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql

i cant connect to mysql database to login cant seem to find the error cuz im a beginner. it always show OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem. I included the network and internet permission in AndroidManifest. I dont know if its the php or the java

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
private EditText etName;
private EditText etPassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
}

/*public void openSales(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, menuActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}*/
public void checkLogin(View arg0) {

    final String name = etName.getText().toString();
    final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    new AsyncLogin().execute(name,password);
}
private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost/THESIS/database.inc.php");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        pdLoading.dismiss();

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, menuActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

this is the php file

```
$servername = "db4free.net:3307/******";
$username = "*****";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "*******";

try {[enter image description here][1]
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die("OOPs something went wrong");
}
   if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
      // Innitialize Variable
      $result='';
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      // Query database for row exist or not
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM asd WHERE  name = :username AND pass = :password';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->rowCount())
      {
         $result="true";    
      }  
      elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
      {
            $result="false";
      }

      // send result back to android
      echo $result;
}
```

here is the img of event log
TIA

Comment: One thing I see is you are using localhost to hit a server from an android device. Replace localhost with the IP of your server. It also helps to use a browser first to make sure the server side is working before you work on the android side

Comment: thx for the answers now its just loading even if the inputs are wrong its just loading, theres no notification says iinvalid username or pass

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 2):

Change `localhost` to `10.0.2.2`. More explained [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html).

Comment: Tom I think you are partly right. On the server side he has db4free.net:3307/*** listed as the database url so the port is 3307. the host is whatever his ip is or the domain name.